# When I update record is throwing an end row in Django

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-models, django-forms

I am getting an error when I try to update a record in Django using a form. I get an error that a record is updating but drop the end rows. How to fix this problem ?

Before updating in Postgresql:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S2uTz.png)

After updating in Postgresql:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IhMWQ.png)

I want to do not change row order but the record change row order when record update.

The view code:

```
from django.shortcuts import render,redirect,get_object_or_404
from Table_definition.forms import TableDefinitionsForms
from Table_definition.models import sysTables

def update_table(request,id):
    process_type = "update"
    table_data = get_object_or_404(sysTables, id = id)
    table_form = TableDefinitionsForms(
        request.POST or None,
        request.FILES or None,
        instance=table_data)

    if table_form.is_valid():
        table_form.save()
        return redirect("Table_definition:table") 

    context = {
        "table_form":table_form,
        "process_type":process_type
    }
    return render(request, 'tableCreate.html', context)
```

The form code:

```
from django import forms
from Table_definition.models import sysTables

class TableDefinitionsForms(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = sysTables
        fields = [
            'name',
            'alias' , 
            'aliasLng1' ,
            'aliasLng2' ,
            'chistory',
            'rhistory',
            'uhistory' ,
            'dhistory' ,
            'log',
        ]
        widgets = {
            'name':forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': '','class':'rc-form-control-input form-control-user'}),
            'alias': forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': '','class':'rc-form-control-input form-control-user'}),
            'aliasLng1': forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': '','class':'rc-form-control-input form-control-user'}),
            'aliasLng2': forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': '','class':'rc-form-control-input form-control-user'}),
            'chistory': forms.CheckboxInput(attrs={'placeholder': '','class':'form-check-input','id':'chistory'}),
            'rhistory': forms.CheckboxInput(attrs={'placeholder': '','class':'form-check-input','id':'rhistory'}),
            'uhistory': forms.CheckboxInput(attrs={'placeholder': '','class':'form-check-input','id':'uhistory'}),
            'dhistory': forms.CheckboxInput(attrs={'placeholder': '','class':'form-check-input','id':'dhistory'}),
            'log': forms.CheckboxInput(attrs={'placeholder': '','class':'form-check-input','id':'log'}),
        }
```

Comment: Can you share exactly what error you're experiencing? Also your `TableDefinitionsForm`

Comment: Have you defined `sysTables.Meta.ordering` or used `.order_by()`? By which field should the model instances be sorted?

Comment: @Ralf I Don't define order_by in Models

Comment: I repeat: By which field should the model instances be sorted?

Comment: @Ralf Which field sorted name field in SysTables

Comment: Also, This record change end row order when update the field  in Database(PostgreSql)